# How do I move a game object instead of the entire scene in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to move `GameObject` between scenes but when I do it moves my whole scene instead of just that one game object. How do I move just the game object and not the whole scene?

I have tried `SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(UIRootObject, sceneToLoad);` and `DontDestroy` but it keeps moving my whole scene new scene.

Comment: Can you show us more context of what you're doing, how you're loading your scene, etc? Ideally, your question should contain every step or line of code we need to reproduce this problem in a new, empty project.

Comment: I think the actual question being asked here is how to transfer a gameObject from one scene hierarchy to another when both scenes are loaded through additive loading.